# Webservice in JBoss doesn't find xsd

Tags: web-services, cxf, jboss7.x, jbossws

I try to implement a first Web service running in JBoss AS 7.2. I use the wsdlLocation-Property to link my service with a predefined wsdl file:

```
@Stateless
@WebServiceProvider(wsdlLocation = "classpath:wsdl\\prototype.wsdl")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyPort {


   @Override
   public PingResponse ping(PingRequest request) {
    //someCode
   }
}
```

In my wsdl I include a xsd file stored in the same directory/classpath location:

```
    <wsdl:types>
       <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://prototype/type" elementFormDefault="qualified">
         <xs:include schemaLocation="prototype.xsd"/>
       </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
```

But it seems, that my jboss don't find this xsd file. Or better, he searches not at the right position. What I'm doing wrong?

```
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/schema): faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'prototype.xsd'.: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\tools\jboss\bin\prototype.xsd (The system cannot find the file specified)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2111)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:808)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:632)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseTypes(WSDLReaderImpl.java:593)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(WSDLReaderImpl.java:305)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2265)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2251)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:261)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:206)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:349)
... 13 more
```

Comment: I don't do myself. I expected JBoss to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ah... I found the solution. The wsdl and xsd must be located in META-INF/wsdl or WEB-INF/wsdl. Another place in classpath seems not to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where an xsd was not being found during deployment.  This problem was intermittent - sometimes the deploy was fine.  My service (wsdl) contract structure was like:

```
WEB-INF
   wsdl
   xsd
   policy
```

I moved xsd and policy under wsdl and the intermittent problem is gone.

Thanks for taking the time to share your answer.  It helped!